# Can i use a `DialogFragment` for a simple yes/no dialog instead of `AlertDialog`? What are the adavntages?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-dialogfragment

According to the docs in Android Developers,

Using DialogFragment to manage the dialog ensures that it correctly handles lifecycle events such as when the user presses the Back button or rotates the screen. The DialogFragment class also allows you to reuse the dialog's UI as an embeddable component in a larger UI, just like a traditional Fragment (such as when you want the dialog UI to appear differently on large and small screens).

But i get the same behavior in an `Alert Dialog` too... That is,there is no affect on the `Alert Dialog` even if i rotate the screen or press the back button.

Then why should i use `Dialog Fragment` instead of `Alert Dialog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DialogFragment is a specialized [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) shaped as a dialog, while AlertDialog is a specialized [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).
A fragment can be bound to the Activity at runtime, so for instance using a DialogFragment for your dialogs will allow you to re-use the same dialog on multiple activities, without having each activity to handle all the code separately.
I definitely recommend to use DialogFragment over AlertDialog.

Comment: I have a lot of different dialogs in my project... Can i still use the `Dialog Fragment` instead of `Alert Dialog`?

Comment: @SaathwikNalige why you think you can't? I think you should think though about your reasoning: if you've already some dialogs working, why to change them? If instead you have a good reason, like "I want to use this dialog when this event happens no matter on which page of my app the user is", then you should definitely move to use DialogFragment. And more generally speaking I recommend to start to use that class. Just make sure you learn how to use it properly, my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dialog Fragment if you want to retain your dialog after the orientation change. The advantage of using a DialogFragment is that all the life cycle of the dialog will be handled for you.

If you have not added `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your manifest then your activity will be recreated on orientation change and your alert dialog **will not be re instantiated after orientation change**. The best way to avoid this problem is by using a DialogFragment. But if you are ignoring orientation change and not recreating the activity by adding above line in manifest then you will not face this problem.